# Reducing the total size of the https request

Tags: web-services, http, optimization, https, request

Assume you have an iPhone application that constantly updates your coordinates by sending the JSON string below;

```
{"id":"abcd","lat":12.2312,"lon":23.0212}
```

And I do send a response like;

```
{"r":"OK"}
```

Now the complicated part is that (I'm using **Heroku** as my deployment service) when I make a request like this it approximately takes **400 bytes** and is used by the data plan. A challange is that in my application I make this request every 2 seconds and the data plan I'm planning to fit this into is not more than **250 MB per month**. However the simple calcution shows that;

**Total:** 400 * 30 * 60 * 24 * 30 = 1 036 800 000 = **~1 GB**, which is **quite outrageous**. So what could be done in order to **reduce the overall data** that is being sent? **Gzip/deflate, reducing the elements sent in header (maybe even removing the request type), shorten the tags**? What could I possibly in order to make it as small as possible?

Comment: If you're doing it every 2 seconds, shouldn't it be 400 * 30 * 60 * 24 * 30?

Comment: You are right! I fixed it and thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Well, each degree of latitude and longitude represents a measurement of approx 68 miles, (~111 km) So even in a car, the vast amount of readings sent will be within the same degree.

Sending the delta of the last and current reading could help make it smaller.

You could also concatenate your lon/lat (or delta) data into one value with a single separator that you parse on the server end.

```
So once a minute:  {"id":"abcd","m":"12.2312|23.0212"} 
Then 29 times:     {"id":"abcd","d":"-25|+68"} etc.
```

You'd need to figure out the server end but that'd be a start.

Comment: It just occurred to me that if you want to have any kind of security at all, your ID will most certainly be longer than abcd, so you need to take that into account as well.

Comment: I added quotes to the value portion of the JSON object. The example was more of a guideline as to how you could make your request smaller.  (your initial question) The exact syntax would need to be figured out by you, I think.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of application needs to know where the user is every 2 seconds? Given the inherent network latency involved with mobile communications in general, many of your requests will be sent before the result from the previous request is returned.